# Depend and if/else in transaction emails in Magento 1

Tags: email-templates, transactional-mail, template-directive

we are investigating some checks in our transactional emails or newsletters and looking at http://merch.docs.magento.com/ce/user_guide/store-operations/email-transactional.html

where we find the code below.

My question: can we use this DEPEND or IF to check the existence or emptiness of a variable? Something like

```
{{if customer.getFirstname()}} 
  {{var customer.firstname}} 
{{else} 
  {{var customer.name}} 
{{/if}}
```

Example from link

```
Depend Condition

{{depend order.getIsNotVirtual()}}

{{/depend}}

{{depend salable}}

{{/depend}}

- If Condition

{{if order.getIsNotVirtual()}}

{{else}}

{{/if}}

(else is optional)
```

Answer (score 45, accepted):

This is exactly the purpose of `{{depend}}` and `{{if}}`.
The only difference between them is that `{{if}}` supports an `{{else}}` statement.
`{{depend}}` is just as an `{{if}}` without an `{{else}}`.
To see how they work refer to `Varien_Filter_Template::dependDirective()` and `Varien_Filter_Template::ifDirective()`.

Comment: and if I want to compare with a string like {{order.getStatus() == 'pending_payment'}} ?

Comment: @DiegoQueiroz Did you find your answer?

Comment: @snh_nl Yes! I Found!

Comment: Can you share the link?

Comment: @DiegoQueiroz please share a link if you still have it.. I really need solution of this problem..

Comment: To the people asking the link from Diego, it's not possible to use ==. Here you can find an alternative and more information -> https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/161041/magento-2-emails-if-statement