# what does the 'depend' key word mean?

Tags: magento-1.8, address, template-directive

I see in the admin panel this code `{{depend prefix}}  {{/depend}}`:

[image: HTML address template]

What does it mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `{{depend}}` condition checks whether there is data for the variable to output.

For instance: If the customer hasn't entered any `prefix` details then there will be no data in the database. The `{{depend}}` condition recognizes this and makes sure that in this case the `prefix` variable isn't displayed in the email template.

To learn more about this [click here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/modules_reference/English/Mage_Adminhtml/system_email_template/index/) and read Marius' answer for [this question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/6488/depend-and-if-else-in-transaction-emails).