# How to write conditional statement using {{if}} in the content of CMS page in admin side?

Tags: magento-1.7, cms, template-directive

I want to show **two different contents** of a cms page (e.g. about us) in **two different themes**.
I know it can be **possible if** I create a **template** where I can have the theme specific condition and **include the template in the cms page** as

```
{{block type="core/template" template="path/to/template.phtml"}}
```

But I want the **contents for both the theme should be handled in the admin cms page content section**.
So **is it possible to apply condition** for themes using `{{if}}` syntax in the cms page content section?

I tried to write a simple `{{if}}` statement for testing but it just printed it in the frontend.

So could anyone suggest what is correct method of writing these statements ?

Answer (score 0):

`{{if}} {{else}} {{depend}}` are conditional macros for use in transactional email templates. They **are not** used in constructing CMS pages.

[For more information on conditional use in transactional emails](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/6488/depend-and-if-else-in-transaction-emails)

[Common CMS Macros AKA ShortCodes or Markup Tags](http://merch.docs.magento.com/ce/user_guide/cms/markup-tag-syntax.html) do not include conditional statements. If you want them, you must create `.phtml` blocks and reference them with a CMS Macro that calls the block.

Comment: I have nearly about 30-35 CMS Pages which I want to display in both the themes differently..So should I create Cms pages for both the themes like about 60-70 Cms pages ?

Answer (score 0):

correct code is:

```
{{if data.request_quote}} Yes {{else}} No {{/if}}
```

You should give `request_quote` a boolean value (or leave it empty if it is not "on")