# Address Template in Magento 2.1.3

Tags: magento-2.1.3, customer-address

I'm trying to modify the address template in Magento through `admin>stores>configuration>customer>customer configuration>Address Templates> HTML`

Can someone tell me the use of {{depend}} and {{if}} in the template or help me modify this one.

In the checkout page, I want to interchange the position of the postcode and city. Also, put the country on top of it and put the street below. This is the order:

- Country
- Postcode
- Region
- City
- Street

**This is the default:**

```
{{depend prefix}}{{var prefix}} {{/depend}}{{var firstname}} {{depend middlename}}{{var middlename}} {{/depend}}{{var lastname}}{{depend suffix}} {{var suffix}}{{/depend}}{{depend firstname}}<br/>{{/depend}}
{{depend company}}{{var company}}<br />{{/depend}}
{{if street1}}{{var street1}}<br />{{/if}}
{{depend street2}}{{var street2}}<br />{{/depend}}
{{depend street3}}{{var street3}}<br />{{/depend}}
{{depend street4}}{{var street4}}<br />{{/depend}}
{{if city}}{{var city}},  {{/if}}{{if region}}{{var region}}, {{/if}}{{if postcode}}{{var postcode}}{{/if}}<br/>
{{var country}}<br/>
{{depend telephone}}T: {{var telephone}}{{/depend}}
{{depend fax}}<br/>F: {{var fax}}{{/depend}}
{{depend vat_id}}<br/>VAT: {{var vat_id}}{{/depend}}
```

**This is my my modified version:**

```
{{depend prefix}}{{var prefix}} {{/depend}}{{var firstname}} {{depend middlename}}{{var middlename}} {{/depend}}{{var lastname}}{{depend suffix}} {{var suffix}}{{/depend}}{{depend firstname}}<br/>{{/depend}}
{{depend company}}{{var company}}<br />{{/depend}}
{{var country}}<br/>
{{if postcode}}{{var postcode}},  {{/if}}{{if region}}{{var region}}, {{/if}}{{if city}}{{var city}}{{/if}}<br/>
{{if street1}}{{var street1}}<br />{{/if}}
{{depend street2}}{{var street2}}<br />{{/depend}}
{{depend street3}}{{var street3}}<br />{{/depend}}
{{depend street4}}{{var street4}}<br />{{/depend}}
{{depend telephone}}T: {{var telephone}}{{/depend}}
{{depend fax}}<br/>F: {{var fax}}{{/depend}}
{{depend vat_id}}<br/>VAT: {{var vat_id}}{{/depend}}
```

But it is not working.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
{{depend prefix}}{{var prefix}} {{/depend}}{{var firstname}} {{depend middlename}}{{var middlename}} {{/depend}}{{var lastname}}{{depend suffix}} {{var suffix}}{{/depend}}{{depend firstname}}<br/>{{/depend}}
{{depend company}}{{var company}}<br />{{/depend}}
{{var country}}<br/>
{{if postcode}}{{var postcode}}<br/>{{/if}}
{{if region}}{{var region}}<br/>{{/if}}
{{if city}}{{var city}}<br/>{{/if}}
{{depend telephone}}T: {{var telephone}}{{/depend}}
{{depend fax}}<br/>F: {{var fax}}{{/depend}}
{{depend vat_id}}<br/>VAT: {{var vat_id}}{{/depend}}
```

I'm not an expert so not sure if this is going to work (and i don't have anything to test it with). But as far as i can see these rules apply :
(source : [depend and if/else in transaction emails](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/6488/depend-and-if-else-in-transaction-emails))

- If statement is used when you want it to output an else (not sure why magento uses it here)
- Depend statements do the same thing but without the else
- tags go before or after the var but always between the depend/if
- A good line of code exists out of depend/if and a var (not sure why country does not have this)

Can you try this and give me feedback? Like i said i don't know anything about it but i would like to work it out together.

Comment: I actually realized that I made a mistake. What I need to change is not the template but the checkout form address.